# about Playframework Global

Tags: playframework, sbt, global

i added some code inside Global.scala, and application.conf  application.global=Global

```
object Global extends WithFilters(new GzipFilter()) with GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application started.")
  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
  }
}
```

Why run 3 times in conole ?

```
[info] application - Application started.
[info] application - Application started.
[info] application - Application started.
[info] wobo - Application started (Dev)
[WARN] [10/21/2013 15:54:50.591] [New I/O worker #1] [EventStream(akka://play)]akka.event-handlers] config is deprecated, use [akka.loggers]
[info] application - Application shutdown...
[info] application - Application shutdown...
[info] application - Application shutdown...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OnStart is might called multiple times because you have dependencies to Play plugins that are older than your application Play version.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/onStart/play-framework/Ly7cy_-SzPI/VMDRmxIYLcEJ)

You can exclude the older Play dependencies in SBT, for example how to do it for the typesafe mail plugin in build.sbt or Build.scala:

```
 "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0" exclude ("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0") exclude("play", "*")
```

I think it happens because Play has a new [Group ID](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/Migration22) so SBT does not recognize it as the same library.